# what is the proper way to save all inputs(without bindig params one by one) with php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Consider that i have 50 input elements in my HTML form, and i want to save them all in a table, so should i create a variable for each input and bind them one by one and insert it into my table?

```
$statement->bindParam(':var1',$name1);
$statement->bindParam(':var2',$address);
$statement->bindParam(':var3',$city); 
$statement->bindParam(':var4',$state);
$statement->bindParam(':var5',$zip_code); 
$statement->bindParam(':var6',$telephone);
$statement->bindParam(':var7',$email); 
$statement->bindParam(':var8',$fiance); 
$statement->bindParam(':var9',$wedding_date);
$statement->bindParam(':var10',$number_of_guest);
$statement->bindParam(':var11',$radio);
$statement->bindParam(':var12',$newspaper); 
// and 13, 14, 15 ...
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to bind every field explicitly. You can just provide the array with all values as a parameter to the `execute()` function.

```
// create the list of the column names from the $_POST keys
$keys = array_keys( $_POST );
// quote keys to prevent SQL injections, then remove surrounding quotes and add ` instead.
foreach ( $keys as $i => $key ) {
    $keys[$i] = '`' . trim( $PDO->quote( $key ), "'" ) . '`';
}
// results in: `var1`,`var2`,`var3`,etc...
$keys = implode( ",", $keys );
// create the list of the placeholders
// results in: ?,?,?,...
$placeholders = implode( ",", array_fill( 0, sizeof( $keys ), "?" ) );
// prepare the statement
// results in: INSERT INTO `table` (`var1`,`var2`,`var3`,etc...) VALUES (?,?,?,...)
$stmt = $PDO->prepare( "INSERT INTO `table` ($keys) VALUES ($placeholders)" );
// execute the statement with the values from the $_POST array
$stmt->execute( array_values( $_POST ) );
```

Comment: im just asking Gerald, is this safe?
no need to use > trim, strip_tags,...?

Comment: Prepared statements help to prevent SQL injections. If you want to remove trailing characters / html / etc.. You still have to do this yourself

Comment: @Amin I updated the answer. The original answer still allowed SQL injections by modifying the names of the input fields. Now this should be fixed. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $statement->bindParam(":".$key,$value);
}
$statement->execute();
```

if your form has the good fields

Comment: This is only a partial answer. How do you build the query with the corresponding placeholders?

Answer (score 0):

use `$statement->execute(array('param1'=>$param1, 'param2'=>$param2))`

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.